# Google Apps Script Replace and update cell within a range

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, return-value

I have a Google spreadsheet that I'm trying to remove the word "woo" within a range of cells
So far I've managed to loop through the results and log the results, however I haven't figured how to update that information in the spreadsheet itself.

Any guidance would be welcomed

Thank you

```
function myFunction () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B:B')
  var data = ss.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var text = data[i].toString();
    var finaltext = text.replace(/woo/g, "");
    data[i] = finaltext;
    Logger.log(data[i]); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Notes:

- Usually `ss` is used as a shorthand for spreadsheet, as it's used on the code for a range it's better to use `range` as a variable name.
- `setValues()` returns a 2D array, so data[i] returns an array of row values rather than a cell value. To get/set cell values, use data[i][0] notation.

Considering the above replace

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B:B')
```

by

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B:B')
```

then add the following line after the for block.

```
range.setValues(data);
```

Regarding `text` var declaration, replace

```
var text = data[i].toString();
```

to

```
var text = data[i][0].toString();
```

Using open ended references like `B:B` could lead to problems. To avoid them be sure to keep the sheet rows at minimum or better instead of using an open ended reference use something like `B1:B10`.

Comment: In OP's script, ``data`` is changed to 1 dimensional array by ``data[i] = finaltext;``. So an error occurs at the added ``range.setValues(data);``. In order to avoid this error, how about adding a modification from ``data[i] = finaltext;`` to ``data[i][0] = finaltext;`` to your answer?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much.